# Add to key-value paired array

Tags: php, arrays, split, key-value

I have 2 arrays. One is initialized with key names but with empty values :

```
$hits_arr = array(
    'HD'=>'',
    'CT'=>'',
    'PS'=>'',
    'LS'=>'',
    );
```

Consider I have such string which is split into 4 different array elements:

```
$val = "8/2/9/4/";
$val = explode("/",$val);
```

My goal is to add each $val values to $hits_array so it would look like :

```
array ( 
'HD'=>"8" 
'CT'=>"2" 
'PS'=>"9" 
'LS'=>"4"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $counter = 0;
 foreach($hits_arr AS $key => $value)
 {
    $hits_arr[$key] = $val[$counter];
    ++$counter;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$hits_arr = array(
    'HD'=>'',
    'CT'=>'',
    'PS'=>'',
    'LS'=>'',
    );


$val = "8/2/9/4";
$val2 = explode("/",$val); 
$count=0;
foreach($hits_arr as $key=>$v){
   $hits_arr[$key]=$val2[$count];
    $count++;
}
var_dump($hits_arr);
```

Your Output will be

```
'HD' => string '8' (length=1)
'CT' => string '2' (length=1)
'PS' => string '9' (length=1)
'LS' => string '4' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

$hits_arr size is 4 and $val size is 5 so both won't combine.
You could try like this

```
$hits_arr['HD'] = $val[0];
print_r($hits_arr);
```